# Why are my MockBeans and MockRestServiceServer not returning proper responses when testing JMS Listener in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-aop, spring-test

I am having an issue when trying to integration test my JMS listener with `Mockito` and `MockRestServiceServer`. Even if I'm using the correct `Mockito.when` annotations, they are coming up as **null**, and the `MockRestServiceServer` is acting as if it isn't being called. If I switch instead to test against the `myService` component that the jms listener calls, the mocks and the `MockRestServiceServer` calls are working as expected, which is puzzling. I am connecting to an embedded ActiveMQ broker for the test and I am using Spring Boot 2.2.8.RELEASE and JDK 8.x if that helps.

Here is the JMS Listener Class

```
@Component
public class MyJmsListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @JmsListener(
            destination = "${jms.queue}",
            containerFactory = "myJmsListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void receive(Message<String> message) {
        myService.process(message);
    }
}
```

Here is the JMS Listener Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class JmsListenerTest {
...
    @MockBean
    private AuthorizationService authorizationService;
...
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate listenerTestJmsTemplate;

    @Value("${jms.queue}")
    private String testDestination;
...
   @Test
    public void testListener() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        //ARRANGE
        String payloadPath = "classpath:payloads/listenerPayload.json";
        String payload = new String(Files.readAllBytes(ResourceUtils.getFile(payloadPath).toPath()));
        String testAuth = "auth";
        Mockito.when(authorizationService.generateTicket(Mockito.any(Headers.class), Mockito.eq("9130353887051456")))
                .thenReturn(testAuth);
        String extPayloadPath = "classpath:payloads/revokeCancelAutoRenewRequestApi.json";
        String extPayload = new String(Files.readAllBytes(ResourceUtils.getFile(extPayloadPath).toPath()));
        mockRestServiceServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(new URI("/test/v3/subscriptions/400367048/something")))
                             .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.content().string(extPayload))
                             .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, testAuth))
                             .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK));
        //ACT
        listenerTestJmsTemplate.convertAndSend(testDestination, payload);
        //ASSERT
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();
        Assert.assertTrue(JmsListenerWrapperConfiguration.latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }
...
}
```

I have a JmsListenerWrapperConfiguration that will allow me to wrap the countdown latch into the jms listener.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class JmsListenerWrapperConfiguration {

    public static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate listenerTestjmsTemplate(ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Wrap the JMS Listeners with a count down latch that will allow us to unit test them.
     * @return The bean post processor that will wrap the JMS Listener.
     */
    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor listenerWrapper() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof MyJmsListener) {
                    MethodInterceptor interceptor = new MethodInterceptor() {

                        @Override
                        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
                            Object result = invocation.proceed();
                            if (invocation.getMethod().getName().equals("listen")) {
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                            return result;
                        }

                    };
                    if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(bean)) {
                        ((Advised) bean).addAdvice(interceptor);
                        return bean;
                    }
                    else {
                        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
                        proxyFactory.addAdvice(interceptor);
                        return proxyFactory.getProxy();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return bean;
                }
            }

        };
    }
}
```

The MockRestServiceServer configuration is defined here.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MockRestServiceServerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        MockRestServiceServerBuilder builder = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate);
        MockRestServiceServer server = builder.bufferContent().build();
        return server;
    }
}
```

The error that I see is as follows.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s).
0 request(s) executed.
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.verify(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:159)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer.verify(MockRestServiceServer.java:116)
```

## Update

I've been debugging and of course the test is running on thread[main], whereas the JMS listener is running on thread[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1], so my question then becomes, what should we do with Mockito mocking when the mocks/verifications need to be used by separate threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `MockRestServiceServer` needed to verify after the latch is awaiting as shown in this code below.

```
Assert.assertTrue(JmsListenerWrapperConfiguration.latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
mockRestServiceServer.verify();
```